# How to compensate for Nginx url rewrite in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, nginx, coffeescript, flask

I have several Flask apps running behind an Nginx reverse proxy. All requests with URLs beginning with /demo/pipeline go to a Flask instance listening on port 7001. I am setting the X-Script-Name header so that my Flask backend can account for this root URL according to http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/. This lets the backend code generate urls relative to the /demo/pipeline root. For example /demo/pipeline/static/utils.js.

Here's a piece of my Nginx config which routes requests to the /demo/pipeline app:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost; 

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7000;
    }

    location /demo/pipeline/ {

        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /demo/pipeline;
        rewrite ^/demo/pipeline/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7001;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now how do I do account for a root URL on the client side? Take one of my jQuery AJAX calls for example:

```
    $.ajax
        type: 'PUT'
        url: '/subreddit/update'
        data: name: @subreddit
        error: -> $(elem)?.text val
```

How can I get this request to go to /demo/pipeline/subreddit/update rather than /subreddit/update? I don't want to hardcode the string '/demo/pipeline' because the code needs to keep working if I either change the route name or remove the Nginx reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add a script like this into your template before you include your main script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var APP_ROOT = {{ app_root|json_encode }};</script>
```

(assuming you've got `json_encode` set up as a filter and `app_root` is defined as your application's root URL.)

Then your CoffeeScript code can do things like this:

```
$.ajax
    type: 'PUT'
    url: "#{APP_ROOT}/subreddit/update"
    data: name: @subreddit
    error: -> $(elem)?.text val
```

By the way, assuming `$` is jQuery, `$(elem)?.text val` is useless; it would work just as well to say `$(elem).text val` since jQuery returns an empty jQuery object (rather than `null` or `undefined`) when nothing matches, and `text` will not error on an empty jQuery object.

Comment: Where do I define app_root? Do I set it in [Environment.globals](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#global-namespace)?

Comment: I just discovered I can access request.headers['X-SCRIPT-NAME'] in the  template which holds '/demo/pipeline'. I think using that instead of defining app_root will be the best way since the definition is in one place at the nginx level.

Comment: @Maros: That would indeed be a better solution.